# Peek() really to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

My problem in most simple expressible way:

According to [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) :

> `Peek()` method exists mainly to support debugging, where you want to
>   see the *elements as they **flow past a certain point** in a pipeline.*

I have a pipe of **10 Meters** and at the distance of **3** and **7 meter** 
from input head i have two markers [aka `peek()`] for checking/debugging my elements.

Now from Input end i am giving input of `1,2,3,4,5`.

At the point x = **4 meter** , i have a `filter()` which filters all elements **less** than and equal to `3`.

Now as per Java doc i should be able to see what has happened to my input in pipeline at distance `3` and `7` meters.

Output at *marker1* at **distance 3** (`.peek()`) should be `1,2,3,4,5` shouldn't be??
and output at *marker2* at **distance 7**  should be `4,5` obviously.

But this is not happening in actual, the output is coming at 1st market(.peek())  just `1,2,3` and at 2nd it is coming `4,5`.

---

The code that i executed to test my theory:

```
final List<Integer> IntList=
    Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    .peek(it -> System.out.println("Before Filtering "+it)) // should print 1,2,3,4,5
    .filter(it -> it >= 3)
    .peek(it -> System.out.println("After Filtering: "+it)) //should print 4,5
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Actual Output:

```
Before Filtering 1
Before Filtering 2
Before Filtering 3
After Filtering: 3
Before Filtering 4
After Filtering: 4
Before Filtering 5
After Filtering: 5
```

Expected Output (what a dev should think after reading [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) (...exists mainly to support debugging, where you want to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline...)

```
    Before Filtering 1
    Before Filtering 2
    Before Filtering 3
    Before Filtering 4
    Before Filtering 5
    After Filtering: 4
    After Filtering: 5
```

If `.peek()` is not just for debugging at a particular point in pipeline then it the def is ambiguous.

*Sorry for my story of Pipe , i thought this way i could explain my best what i want to ask.*

Comment: I think that output should be as it pass through the peek, i am asking the question not stating anything.

Comment: i like the question because it helped me clear up my misconception and i suspect **a lot** of people fell for the same fallacy ... its easy to misunderstand that streams are lazily evaluated, in fact i already wrote important code under the assumption that the individual steps are always evaluated in a non-lazy fashion *(and yet the code worked flawlessly)*. Just ignore the trolls ... its common to downvote everything you dont like here on troll overflow.

Comment: The fact that all intermediate stream operations are lazy is very well documented.

Comment: @CommonMan I did not get your claim as valid and thus I asserted a claim that it is not valid. What I asked you to do is to *justify* your claim to better understand what misconception needs to be cleared up. I am also not sure what you mean by "giving downvotes is very easy"; I am not one of the two people who downvoted your post. I am in no way trying to *suppress" or "quench" your question; casting a doubt of your question's claims is a means of academic discourse and is in and of itself separate from suppressing the question.

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov mate i really dont have hard feelings for you, but understand me i have given some good stream answers on SO and i was in misconception about .peek() till date and i wanted to just torch a light to similar people who are like me by the above question. As a saying goes: if you can make someone understand a concept means you have got the concept.

Comment: @CommonMan I agree--and as a part of the academic discourse per my experience the best way to start is to better understand one's prior understanding/misconceptions.

Comment: `it -> it >= 3` — I assume you also expect *"After Filtering: 3"* to be printed.

Comment: I don’t get your reasoning about a real pipe. When you place two workers at a pipe, to give a shout when they see a particular element, they will shout right the way you see the printed messages with the Stream implementation. To get your expected result, each of them would have to cut the pipe and insert a reservoir to hold back all elements until seeing the last one, before allowing them to flow further. That’s not an ordinary pipe.

Comment: @Holger, i got it that it is not ordinary pipe and there is concept of Lazy initialization. I am sure many people would have misconception like what i had yesterday.

Comment: @CommonMan I know, this misconception is not uncommon. But that’s usually because people do not think of a pipe, whereas I’d expect reasoning about a pipe should actually lead into the right direction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. Streams may be evaluated lazily as needed, and the order of operations is not strongly defined, especially when you're `peek()`ing. This allows the streams API to support very large streams without significant waste of time and memory, as well as allowing certain implementation simplifications. In particular, a single stage of the pipeline **need not** be fully evaluated before the next stage is.

Suppose how wasteful the following code would be, given your assumptions:

```
IntStream.range(1, 1000000).skip(5).limit(10).forEach(System::println);
```

The stream starts with one million elements and ends up with 10. If we evaluated each stage fully, our intermediate would be 1 million, 999995, and 10 elements, respectively.

As a second example, the following stream cannot be evaluated a stage at a time (because `IntStream.generate` returns an **infinite** stream):

```
IntStream.generate(/* some supplier */).limit(10).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Your pipeline does indeed pass every single element through the first `peek`, and then only a subset through the second `peek`. However, the pipeline performs this evaluation in an element-major rather than stage-major order: it evaluates the pipe for 1, dropping it at the filter, then 2. Once it evaluates the pipe for 3, it passes the filter thus both peek statement execute, and the same then occurs for 4 and 5.

Comment: Actually, `3` is also included in the result, since `i >= 3`.

Comment: @MCEmperor Thanks for the heads-up; just fixed the mistake.

Answer (score 12):

The answer from Andrey Akhmetov is correct, but I want to add to it, because there are two issues here.  One is the general issue of the semantics of stream pipelines -- which is really what your question is about.  The secondary one is about the meaning, and limitations, of `peek()`.

To the main question -- which has nothing to do with `peek()`, except that's how you are observing the state of what's going on -- your intuition about streams is simply incorrect.  There is no reason to believe that in:

```
collection.stream()
          .filter(x -> x.foo() > 3)
          .map(X::toBar)
          .forEach(b -> System.out.println("Bar: " + b);
```

that all the filtering happens before all the mapping before all the printing.  The stream is free to interleave filtering and mapping and printing in any order it likes.  (There are some ordering guarantees *in the aggregate*.)  The benefit here is that this is often more performant, more parallelizable, and more robust in some situations with infinite streams. As long as you follow the rules (i.e., don't rely on the side-effects of one stage in another stage), you won't be able to tell the difference, except maybe that your code runs faster.

The reason for the wiggly language of `peek()` is that for pipelines like:

```
int size = collection.stream()
                     .map(...)
                     .peek(...)
                     .count()
```

We can evaluate the answer without doing *any* mapping (since map() is known to be a size-preserving operation.)  The requirement to always provide the elements at `peek()` points would have undermined a number of useful optimizations.  So the implementation is free to elide the entire middle of the pipeline if it can prove it won't affect the *answer*.  (It may produce fewer *side-effects*, but if you care about side-effects so much, maybe you shouldn't be using streams.)

Comment: How does stream decide how to order the ops? Are they indeed fully stochastic? To extend your example, consider:
`xs.stream().filter(x -> x != null).filter(x -> x.foo() > 3).map(X::toBar).forEach(.....)`
I would imagine in this example we would have a strongly ordered invocations of `filter()` (to elide the NPE) - am I wrong in this expectation and how can we predict the order of operations? Can you point to JavaDocs that would be good entry points in this investigation?

Comment: Intermediate operations are applied in the order they appear in the code.  However, sometimes they may be elided in entirety (e.g., `sortedSet.stream().sorted()` won't re-sort) and sometimes no data needs to be drawn from the source if the answer can be determined without it (e.g., `list.stream().map(f).count()` doesn't need to draw any elements.)