# Java streams - peek and skip

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm studying for an exam and I am confused over peek. Demo code:

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    .peek(x -> System.out.print("A" + x))
    .skip(6)
    .peek(x -> System.out.print("B" + x))
    .forEach(x -> System.out.println("C" + x));
```

Output:

```
A1A2A3A4A5A6A7B7C7
A8B8C8
A9B9C9
```

Can someone explain what's happening here? All I know is that `skip(6)` skips the first 6 elements and peek will print the values of the stream at that given moment.

Comment: Read answers from this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54405863/peek-really-to-see-the-elements-as-they-flow-past-a-certain-point-in-a-pipelin

Comment: By the way, whoever set this was incredibly mean with their completely illogical choice of `print` and `println`s. This is much easier to reason about if every statement was `println`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that example is unnecessarily obtuse.

Here's effectively the exact same problem but with output that I believe makes it much more clear what is going on. It prints one line per item in the stream.

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
    .peek(x -> System.out.println())                //always prints
    .peek(x -> System.out.print("A" + x + " "))     //always prints
    .skip(6)                                        //"conditional"
    .forEach(x -> System.out.print("B" + x));       //sometimes prints
```

Output

```
A1 
A2 
A3 
A4 
A5 
A6 
A7 B7
A8 B8
A9 B9
```

Integers 1 - 6 only make it as far as the `skip` operation which drops them on the floor. They are not allowed to make it as far as `B`. The `skip` acts like a barrier.

The remaining items are allowed to pass through the `skip` "barrier" and do make it to `B`.

Comment: I think the *point* of the *exam* was to be partly "obtuse", in order to *challenge* the person taking the exam, to better gauge whether they understood what was going on.

Comment: @Andreas Exam questions that aim to deliberately confuse or trick students are poor exam questions. If that was aim, it's stupid. I like to give the question setter a bit more credit and like to believe that they came up with a bad question accidentally. I think that this example assesses the same understanding of Java streams -- which was presumably what it was aiming to assess -- without producing gibberish output.

Answer (score 1):

The way you printed it was sort of complicated.  Imho, it was easier to see by placing a newline at the beginning of the first print statement.

```java
      Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).peek(x -> System.out.print("\nA" + x)).skip(
            1).peek(x -> System.out.print("B" + x)).forEach(
                  x -> System.out.print("C" + x));
```

Produces

```
A1
A2B2C2
A3B3C3
A4B4C4
A5B5C5
A6B6C6
```

Clearly a personal preference.  It just shows the first one printed by itself and the rest in sequence as they should be.

Comment: A bit ironic that you said the way it was printed was complicated, and posted a code sample formatted like that... :)

Comment: You're right!  I was in the midst of changing it when you commented.